# Exchange 2010 as events calendar server solution for multiple calendars and universal client access

Tags: exchange, calendar

I understand Exchange 2010 with SP1 has the ability to publish calendars as .ics URLs - can it do that for shared calendars (i.e. group calendars, not personal calendars) and can it have multiple calendars in this form?

I'm looking for a solution that will provide a client with the ability to publish multiple event calendars and have those calendars viewable by lots of different client types both individually and with an aggregate view.

Calendars need to be viewable natively in various versions of Outlook (2003, 2007, 2010), Apple MacOSX iCal, on iPhone/iPad/Android/other smart phone, within a Sharepoint portal (could be a custom webpart).  Viewing is anonymous.

Updates could be via Outlook or a HTML interface (i.e. OWA).

The client currently has Exchange 2007 and is considering an upgrade to Exchange 2010 - are either of these capable of presenting readonly views of multiple shared calendars to non-MS clients?  Are they capable if presenting aggregate views of shared calendars?

Are there better solutions?

Comment: I'm confused by "calendars not associated with a mailbox". Everything has an associated mailbox, including calendars. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, don't know that much about exchange.  I mean group or shared calendars, not personal calendars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.stevieg.org/2010/06/calendar-sharing-improvements-coming-in-exchange-2010-sp1/

Read through the whole article, Exchange 2010 does offer this feature - I haven't used this as I only came to remember this today, I was on the look for this for a while and your question reminded me off that :-)

Comment: Thanks rihatum.  I think this is exactly what my client needs.  Now to see if they can get over the hurdle of updating from Exchange 2007